# if conditions are being ignored

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

currently,the conditions of my if loop are not being respected. no matter what I enter for x, the statements inside the for loop still run. The idea here is that the user can enter data, and if they want to change the data before the next step, they can. At the end of the while loop, they should have the option to jump back to the start, or exit the while loop. I initially attempted to do a while loop inside a while loop, but that returned no result at all.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    dataSet myData;
    int a, b, c, d, x, y;
    cout << "2 to start, 1 to fail." << endl;
    cin >> y >> x;
    while (y == 2) {
        if (x == 1);
        {
            cout << "please enter 4 numbers: " << endl;
            cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;
            int start[4] = { a, b, c, d };
            myData.addElements(start);
            x = myData.moveForward;
        }
        myData.beginProcess();
        y = myData.moveForward;
        x = myData.moveForward;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ik that the loop back into the start of if isnt gonna loop, and am working on that. it's leftover from when I was trying to make it a while loop.

Comment: All this could've been easly detected if you've used a debugger. A debugger is a programmer's best friend! Get to know it well

Comment: good to know, still a beginner, and missed the semicolon. XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` statement does nothing, because:

```
if (x == 1);
           ^~~~ empty statement!
```

I suggest your raise your warning level to at least `/W3`, then the compiler would have warned you:

```
warning C4390: ';' : empty controlled statement found; is this the intent?
```

Comment: woops didnt even see the semicolon XD

Answer (score 0):

There should be no ; after the if statement

Comment: woops typo i feel stupid now. bet thats why my while statement wasnt working either XD

Answer (score 0):

```
if (x == 1);
```

`if (x == 1)` will execute the next instruction. Which is just `;`, the "void" instruction.

After that, the `if` block has ended and continues executin the next of the code (the nested block you think was to be executed only if `x == 1`)

Comment: woops missed the semicolon my bad XD hate typos XD